# CLICK 1 button from same buttons using pycharm selenium

Tags: selenium, button, xpath, pycharm

i have two buttons from which i want to click one button, ID for those both button is same. How can i distinguiush between these two buttons.

Action
                                                

                                                Action

Comment: <a id="LnkDetails" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdParent$ctl02$LnkDetails','')">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Action
                                                </a>________________________Button1

Comment: <a id="LnkDetails" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdParent$ctl03$LnkDetails','')">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Action
                                                </a>_______________Button2

Comment: i have used this but it is not working_____________________________driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdParent$ctl03$LnkDetails").click()

Comment: Getting error________________selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdParent$ctl03$LnkDetails"}

Comment: can you share the link to the webpage and also highlight the element? thanks

Comment: Check if this works `from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
   WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href~'grdParent$ctl02']")))`

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@id='LnkDetails'])[2]").click()
except:
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "LnkDetails").click()
```